C++ Find Saddle Point Code - Errors Under specific Cases?
So, I am taking a course for C++, and one of the questions is to write code to find the Saddle Point (largest of row, smallest of column) of a 2D array. My code does not produce any issues with the sample inputs provided, but does not pass certain test cases itself. Could I have some help with it please?
Constraints - 5*5 grid of numbers(15for array size is used in case of special test cases)
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int max[15], min[15];
    int a[15][15];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        min[i] = 99999999;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
            if(a[i][j] < min[j]){
                min[j] = a[i][j];
            }
            if(a[i][j] > max[i]){
                max[i] = a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
            if(a[i][j] == min[j] && a[i][j] == max[i]){
                cout << i << ' ' << j << ' ' << a[i][j] << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "not found" << endl;
    return 0;    
}

There is not much I can say about what I tried as I don't know what the test cases for the question actually are.

Side note, doesn't your course teach you about std::vector? Using "fixed sized arrays" makes your code fragile (e.g. dependent on 15 being large enough), with std::vector you can use push_back to add items at runtime.  Also whenever possible you should use range based for loops. And your course should have taught you not to use using namespace std;

Also show your teacher this: CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C" and let him read the C++ core guidelines and update his material accordingly.

In C++ array and vector indexing starts at zero. Writing code that uses one based indexing for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) shows an unwillingness to accept the common conventions of the language.

I don't know what the test cases for the question actually are. -- min[i] = 99999999; -- What if one or more of the values is greater than 99999999?  Assuming that the int is at least 32-bit, the value 99999999 is much smaller than std::numeric_limits<int>::max();.  You need to specify what the absolute minimum and maximum values that the matrix could have.

@PepijnKramer As far as I know, no. The course is in Mandarin, so I have little knowledge of what you mean. And could you clarify about not using (don’t know how to make code seperate) (using namespace std)?

@john I completely know this, in fact, I use int i = 0; wherever possible, rather than 1. However, in this particular question, setting i as 1 causes correct results, whereas i = 0 doesn’t. I have no idea why.

@PaulMcKenzie Thank you. However, our teacher has not taught us this yet, and thus we are expected not to use this.

@PaulMcKenzie I recently checked, and the upper limit is much less than what i have used. Thanks for the suggestion, however.

@PepijnKramer Also, I think you are overestimating our progress within the course. We have not been taught any of what you have mentioned. I can somewhat understand what you mean, and it seems to be sound advice, if only  I knew how to implement it. Thank you.

@FelixFung However, our teacher has not taught us this yet -- You have to realize we have no idea what your teacher has taught you.   All we can do is assume you are a C++ programmer who understands (or learns) what is mentioned in the comments (and in the list of answers).  Second thing is that you asked us for test cases that fail -- given what you wrote, the test cases that will fail are ones that have a maximum that is greater than your artificial max of 99999999 (even if you fix the uninitialized min mentioned in the answers).

Actually, it it max that is uninitialized, not min.  But regardless, this is why you need to say what the actual constraints are up-front.  If you had mentioned that the values in the matrix have a range of 0 <= n <= 99999999 or similar, then maybe can assume that the test cases are not tricking you and giving you values that are outside this range.   But not mentioning this makes your code look incorrect (it is incorrect) if we assume that any int can be held in the matrix.

Maybe I do overestimate. But I also think your teacher should show std::vector very early on. (Assuming you are attending a C++ class, datastructure teachers usually teach a strange mix of "C" and "C++")

@PepijnKramer I see, thank you. I will pass this information on to my teacher.

@PaulMcKenzie Thank you for this very good advice. I am rather new to this, so this criticism is very helpful.

One error in your code is that you are using the max array uninitialised. In particular you test the content of the array here if(a[i][j] > max[i]){ before max[i] has been given a value. This results in your code having undefined behaviour.
This would be better
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    min[i] = 99999999;
    max[i] = -99999999;
}


I see, thank you for this advice. I am yet to implement it, but it makes sense. Thank you.
